# How to show menu and title on all activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have created three activities explore/deals and packages. I have created my menu using drawer layout. I would like to saw my menu icon on each activity screen. I have created a base activity for menu items and extends that to all activities. I'm attaching my homeactivity code, base activity code and explore activity code below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhbgN.jpg)

[image]
Here is explore activity code

```
package com.example.windows81.travelspoc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ExploreActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_explore);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);  <- remove this
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is my homeactivity code

```
package com.example.windows81.travelspoc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


ViewPager viewPager;
LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
NavigationView mNavigationView;
private int dotscount;
private ImageView[] dots;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mtoggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mtoggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, 
R.string.close);
    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mtoggle);
    mtoggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 2000, 4000);

    dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

    for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){
        dots[i] = new ImageView(this);


dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),
R.drawable.incative_dot));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8,0);

        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);
    }

dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), 
R.drawable.ic_active));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int 
positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), 
R.drawable.incative_dot));
            }



dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable
(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_active));

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mtoggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.explore:
            // do what you want here
            myMethod();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        HomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1){
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                }else{
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }


            }
        });

    }
}

public void myMethod(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ExploreActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void exploreActivity(View view){
    myMethod();
}

public void packagesActivity(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,PackagesActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void dealsActivity(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DealsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.explore) {
        myMethod();
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Here is my Base activity code

```
package com.example.windows81.travelspoc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Windows 8.1 on 11/15/2017.
 */

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.explore:
            myMethod();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void myMethod(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ExploreActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void exploreActivity(View view){
    myMethod();
}

public void packagesActivity(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,PackagesActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void dealsActivity(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DealsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: you have to create a BaseActivity and use the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) in it. all your other activities should extend this baseactivity

Comment: you can use fragments instead of activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base activity in which u write code for menu items then extend the base activity to all your inner activities.

**For Title**

Create a common title layout.

Then in your HomeActivity

```
abstract class HomeActivity extends Activity {
  protected TextView txtHeading;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }


  protected void setHeading(int resId) {
     if(tv_title == null)
     txtHeading = findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
     if(tv_title != null)
       txtHeading.setText(resId);
  }
}
```

Then in other activities like activity_main.xml

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      setHeading(R.string.heading_main);
   }
}
```

same goes for other activities

**For Same Menu Option**

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    // other overidden methods

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item:
                // do what you want here
                return true;
            default:
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in child activity

```
  public class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity { 


    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);  <- remove this
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
    }
```

Comment: I have extend my Homeactivity with inneractivities and i'm able to saw the menu icon, but the menu is not listing and home activity title is showing on all activities

Comment: @ShyjuKrishnankutty updated my answer ,please check it

Comment: your question is still not clear , please explain better i am not able to understand

Comment: I have updated my question. Hope it will give you more idea about what my issue is.

Answer (score 1):

If you have same menu through out all activities then i will advice you to create one

**BaseActivity** then extends it to **AppcompatActivity**

Make **Activity1** -> extends **BaseActivity**

Magic comes here -> You don't have to use setContentView for all the time.

Make **BaseActivity** with One XML -> FrameLayout -> with Your

ToolBar & FrameLayout

Now in the **Activity1** inflate your view in **FrameLayout** of **BaseActivity**

And follow the same system for all the activities.

I had the same situation -> I had to display sideMenu in every **Activity** so i ended up with this solution.